# How to bind a Promise to a component property?

Tags: angular

I have a promise object needs to be parsed to another component, how to achieve this so that when the promise in `component-one` is resolved, the promise object parsed to `component-two` can also be resolved?

#### ComponentOne excerpt

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component-one',
  template: `
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <component-two [promisedData]="promisedData"></component-two>
    `,
  directives: [ComponentTwo]
  })
export class ComponentOne {
  promisedData: Promise<any>;

  constructor () {
    this.promisedData = new Promised(resolve => {
             setTimeout(function(){
                 resolve('Test');
              }, 1000);
    });
  }
}
```

#### ComponentTwo excerpt

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component-two',
  template: `
      <h2>
        {{processedData}} 
        // the {{processedData}} is undefined becaused the 
        // resolved promise doesn't get to parse to the component-two.
      </h2>
    `,
  inputs: ['promisedData']
  })
export class ComponentTwo {
  promisedData: Promise<any>;
  processedData: string;

  constructor () {
    PromisedData.then(data => this.processedData = data);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some code that shows what you try to accomplish?

Comment: I have provided a demonstration of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easy way is to just add the `async` pipe to your template like this:

`{{promisedData | async}}`

Edit: here's a working example showing the `async` pipe: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JKNmp1Z8XYQfUVmfUEau?p=preview)

Edit2: Plunker showing OnInit: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r8nXsaWbrR479MvcKiIZ?p=preview)

Comment: I adjusted the code above, please take another look, I have issue when the promisedData gets resolved in `component-one`, the one in `component-two` doesn't get to sync.

Comment: How to use the promisedData in the constructor? I added something to the constructor -- http://plnkr.co/edit/po34BB8Ff2DysWevc6XO?p=preview

Comment: You can't use it in the constructor. The `@Input` hasn't been parsed yet. Use OnInit. See added plunker and read: http://learnangular2.com/lifecycle/

Comment: That's what I am missing! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Mark Meyer is absolutely correct.

However, If your promised value is an object, and you need to access a property of it, you can write:

```
  {{ (promissedObject | async).property }}
```