# Can you bind a promise to a scope property in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

On this [blog](http://jensrantil.github.io/refreshable-angularjs-service.html) I read:

> ...note that we are storing a promise to the scope. This is not the same as the actual list. AngularJS automatically resolves this as the actual returned list and presents it in the generated HTML.

Does this mean I can do this:

```
angular.module('app', []).service('Data', function($q) {
  return {
   getItems: function() {
     return $q.when(['cat', 'dog']);
   }
  }
})
.controller('MyController', function(Data, $scope) {
  $scope.items = Data.getItems();
});
```

Instead of this?

```
.controller('MyController', function(Data, $scope) {
   Data.getItems().then( function(result) {
     $scope.items = result;
   });
});
```

If so, where is the documentation for it? I've searched through the docs to no avail.

I tried in a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/PEzGgakBEK7V7YFbo89C?p=preview) but got nowhere.

I also found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980973/how-to-bind-a-promise-to-a-component-property) that mentions the **async** directive. Again, I struggle to find any documentation on this.

Am I confusing Angular1 with Angular2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used to be able to do that with Angular 1.2 (which, seems to have been a mistake).  1.3 and newer requires you to unwrap the promise before binding.

**Edit:**  This question may be a duplicate [Angular JS: how to bind to promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033118/angular-js-how-to-bind-to-promises)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe? You can access the values in your plunkr like this if you want:

```
i in items.$$state.value
```

Here's an updated plunkr that will simulate a http request via a timeout:

https://plnkr.co/edit/aWfDWJWIJnsnXLpTEIol?p=preview

Comment: Clever trick there, although I was more wanting to know if this was a feature of Angular I had missed. Cheers.